# Are loss functions only used to evaluate estimators?

Tags: loss-functions, estimators

Given the likelihood $p(x;\theta)$, we want to construct an estimator $\hat\theta(X)$ that takes in the observation $x$ and returns an estimate of $\theta$. There are many different ways to evaluate our estimator $\hat\theta(X)$. For example, the bias of $\hat\theta(X)$ is
$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\hat\theta(X) - \theta]
$$
and the mean squared-error (MSE) of $\hat\theta(X)$ is
$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[(\hat\theta(X) - \theta)^2]
$$
Both the bias and the MSE are functions of $\hat\theta$ and $\theta$, and it seems at first glance that they are examples of loss functions, since loss functions are also functions of $\hat\theta$ and $\theta$.

More generally, in the context of statistics, does this mean that loss functions are only used to evaluate estimators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you defined them uses the concept of an estimator, so it would be hard to consider them separately. However, the terms such as *utility* and *loss* come from [decision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_theory) that is much broader than statistics or machine learning, because it concerns general decision making (choosing between estimators is a decision).

Comment: Isn't an estimator just a decision of what to do with your observed data? In other words, we choose the decision (estimator) that minimizes some loss function.

Comment: @mhdadk estimator estimates something from data, you don’t always estimate things from data when making decisions. For example, you could make decisions based on subjective costs.